# Property 'onDidDismiss' does not exist on type ionic 4 and Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am developing an app and I have the next class in TypeScript.

I want to try to get the data in a method of type callback in ´ModalController´ when it dismiss the modal:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; 
import {NavController, ModalController} from '@ionic/angular'; 
import { Router } from '@angular/router'; 
import { HomePage } from '../home/home.page'; 
import {AddItemPage} from '../add-item/add-item.page';

@Component({   
  selector: 'app-todo',   
  templateUrl: './todo.component.html',   
  styleUrls: ['./todo.component.scss']
})

export class TodoComponent implements OnInit {

  public items;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public modalCtrl: ModalController) {
    this.ionViewDidLoad();    
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  async addItem()  {
    // Create a modal using MyModalComponent with some initial data 
     const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({   
        component: AddItemPage,  componentProps: {
           'prop1': "cadena!!!!!!!"   
        } 
     }).then(function(modal) {   
        return modal.present(); 
     });

     modal.onDidDismiss(() => {
        // Call the method to do whatever in your home.ts
        console.log('Modal closed');
    });
  }
}
```

I got this error:

> core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'onDidDismiss' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'onDidDismiss' of undefine

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal#usage

Comment: @FernandoPie were you able to solve this?

Comment: @sebaferreras OH yeah sebas  I have found my solution here:https://medium.com/@david.dalbusco/how-to-declare-and-use-modals-in-ionic-v4-4d3f42ac30a3

Comment: @FernandoPie ok glad to hear that you solved the issue. When asking a question on SO please take some time to review the answers to see if any of them may solve your issue, and if they don’t and you find a better solution, you can add your own answer. That way you can accept an answer and close the question. Otherwise your question will remain open which make other users think that it doesn’t have a solution at all. The goal is just to help some other users facing the same issue to find the way to solve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How is related in this post:https://medium.com/@david.dalbusco/how-to-declare-and-use-modals-in-ionic-v4-4d3f42ac30a3
My error was just How I was creating the modal. I have followed this code to create my modal property.

```
async openModal() {
    const modal: HTMLIonModalElement =
       await this.modalController.create({
          component: DatePickerModal,
          componentProps: {
             aParameter: true,
             otherParameter: new Date()
          }
    });

    modal.onDidDismiss().then((detail: OverlayEventDetail) => {
       if (detail !== null) {
         console.log('The result:', detail.data);
       }
    });

    await modal.present();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `await` to create the modal, you don't need to use the `then` like that.

Please try the following:

```
async addItem()  {

  // Create the modal
  const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({   
    component: AddItemPage,
    componentProps: {
      'prop1': "cadena!!!!!!!"   
    } 
  });

  // Present the modal
  return await modal.present();

  // Wait for the modal to be dismissed before continuing...
  const eventDetails = await modal.onDidDismiss();

  if (eventDetails) {
    console.log(eventDetails.data);
  }

  // ...

}
```

The code above assumes you're returning something when dismissing the modal, like this:

```
// Dismiss the modal returning some data object
modalController.dismiss({
  'result': 'This is the result returned by the modal!'
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try :

```
const modal = await modalController.create({...});
const { data } = await modal.onDidDismiss();
console.log(data);
```

As per official [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal#returning-data) .